# Is there a way to instruct Elasticsearch to only return matches from one node

Tags: elasticsearch

We are designing a large framework around Elasticsearch and are investigating a few options.

For some complex analysis jobs, we are looking for a way to retrieve data from only the currently connected Elasticsearch node, i.e. only data from the primary shard on the node that I am connected to via the client or no result if there is no primary shard located on this node?

Is this possible via some search attribute or via more specialized setup?

We want to use the normal Elasticsearch functionality as much as possible, naturally, but sometimes there might be queries that need this type of access, is this doable with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the search to specific shards using the *preference* query string parameter (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-preference.html).

e.g. by sending your query to `http://ES-NODE:9200/INDEXNAME/_search?preference=_shards:1`

you should be able to restrict the query to shard 1

Comment: Thanks, I think "_only_node" is what I am actually looking for here!